# Power BI Custom Visual development - Cannot set height for div

Tags: typescript, powerbi

I am trying to develop custom visual for Power BI.
I have div element with leaflet map. When I do not set a height, visual is empty. I can set a height with `this.mapDiv.style.height="300px";`

But this is fixed. 
How can I set height dynamically by viewport?

This is my code

```
private mapDiv: HTMLElement;

    constructor(options: VisualConstructorOptions) {

        this.mapDiv = document.createElement("div");
        this.mapDiv.id = "mapid";   
        options.element.appendChild(this.mapDiv);

        var map = L.map('mapid');
            map.setView([48.14, 17.12], 13);

        L.tileLayer('https:....', {
                minZoom: 4,
                maxZoom: 18,
         }).addTo(map);

    }

    public update(options: VisualUpdateOptions) {
        // this.mapDiv.style.height = "300px"; WORKS
        this.mapDiv.style.height = options.viewport.height.toString(); // DOESNT WORKS !!!
    }
```

Can you help pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append "px" back to `options.viewport.height` as it's just a number.

i.e. You can try

```
this.mapDiv.style.height = options.viewport.height + "px";
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because `options.viewport.height` is number and `this.mapDiv.style.height` is string.

Comment: @TomášČičman I've revisited my own custom visual and modified the answer above. Hope it works for you.

Comment: @TomášČičman Feel free to add the `.toString()` part but in my custom visual it's not needed.